# PHP - assigning function return to variable

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that returns a random password.  How do I echo out the password that is generated?

```
<?php

function generatePassword($length=9, $strength=0) {
    $vowels = 'aeuy';
    $consonants = 'bdghjmnpqrstvz';
    if ($strength & 1) {
        $consonants .= 'BDGHJLMNPQRSTVWXZ';
    }
    if ($strength & 2) {
        $vowels .= "AEUY";
    }
    if ($strength & 4) {
        $consonants .= '23456789';
    }
    if ($strength & 8) {
        $consonants .= '@#$%';
    }

    $password = '';
    $alt = time() % 2;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        if ($alt == 1) {
            $password .= $consonants[(rand() % strlen($consonants))];
            $alt = 0;
        } else {
            $password .= $vowels[(rand() % strlen($vowels))];
            $alt = 1;
        }
    }
    return $password;
}

?>
```

Comment: do you wrote all that code and you don't know about echo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As prodigitalson mentioned, you can directly `echo` out the return value or assign it to a variable, eg

```
$password = generatePassword();
```

Answer (score 2):

err.. change

```
return $password;
```

to

```
echo $password;
```

Or.. better yet:

```
$somevar = generatePassword();
echo $somevar;
```

Comment: Functions that echo are so Wordpress. Also, "Wordpress" is my new vernacular for "bad", hopefully it catches on ;)

Comment: Hahaha, I agree on that (function that echo are bad). But, I don't want to start 'religion' wars ;)

Comment: @Phil Or you could just use the right function. `get_` in front of the function name will **return** the output instead of echo'ing.